# F the Planet - Enigmatic Puzzle

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, geometry

[image: F the Planet]

Clues: [contextual images]

Eye

D G C F U K L K A Z 
W A N C H Q T O U I
A E I X L U M N R J
M A M V A I R
S A E T S Z B

F F F F

Instructions: Name That Character

_ _ _ A _ _ _

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have seen a puzzle like this before in the past, leading me to

> arranging the four "F"s in the grid like so, fitting all of them inside.
>  [image: The completed grid]
>  Yielding us [FUTURAMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futurama).

As for the answer,

> the instructions ask for us to name that character.
>  A character from Futurama whose name fits within the given blanks is [TURANGA Leela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leela_(Futurama)).

OP Edit:

> The eye above the first F points to a cyclops character. Also the title of the puzzle hints at the Planet Express, the ship piloted by Turanga Leela in the show.