# Killer Capybaras

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, geometry

[image: Killer Capybaras]

Clues: [contextual images]
[2 triangles]
[2 trapezoids]
[1 rectangle full of letters listed in-order]

Instructions: Name That Poison

_ _ _ A _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

Hint:

> Look at the solution to this puzzle: [F the Planet - Enigmatic Puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120614/f-the-planet-enigmatic-puzzle?rq=1)

Comment: Are the shapes the correct scale relative to the letter grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer:

> Iocane powder

fits with _ _ _ A _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

and

> is a deadly poison in The Princess Bride
>  which is referenced by the puzzle title ... Killer Capybaras = Rodents Of Unusual Size (ROUS)

but

> I can't make the shapes fit in a helpful way

Since you got the right answer,
OP Spoiler:

> [image: AYW Explaination]